# c++ error reading values from file

Tags: c++

This is my first post so if I have written or formated something against forums rules please show some understanding. I also happens to be a novice programmer in C++ so if you could please write somewhat simplified if possible.

I need to read some values from a file named text.txt which is like that (total 13 columns):

```
1 2 B5 AA 120 0 100 1.5 1.5 G 0 0 0 \n
1 2 B6 AB 120 0 100 1.5 1.5 G 0 0 0 \n
1 2 B7 AC 120 0 100 1.5 1.5 G 0 0 0 \n
...
```

The above file can have an undetermined number of lines. It is generated through an other routine.

I made a routine in code::blocks. I have made three matrices holding the above data as integers, doubles, strings. The deceleration I have made is as follows:

```
int c1, c2, c7, i = 0, nNumPipes;
double c5, c6, c8, c9, c11, c12, c13;
string c3, c4, c10;

int PipeI[][3] = {0};
double PipeD[][6] = {0};
string PipeS[10000][3];
```

Then I use the following syntax to read the lines:

```
ifstream inf("C:\\text.txt");
while (inf >> c1 >> c2 >> c3 >> c4 >> c5 >> c6 >> c7 >> c8 >> c9 >> c10 >> c11 >> c12 >> c13)
{
    PipeI[i][0] = c1;      
    PipeI[i][1] = c2;      
    PipeS[i][0] = c3;       
    PipeS[i][1] = c4;      
    PipeD[i][2] = c5;       
    PipeI[i][2] = c7;      
    PipeD[i][0] = c8;       
    PipeD[i][1] = c9;     
    PipeS[i][2] = c10;    
    PipeD[i][5] = c11;   
    PipeD[i][3] = c12;     
    PipeD[i][4] = c13;    

    i++;
}

nNumPipes = i;
```

The code however fails in this 'while' loop. Do I miss something?

The error message I get is a window saying "xxx.exe has stop working".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Start small.  Break up your input operations so there is only one item read in each one and see which one is failing.  Your declarations for `PipeI` and PipeD` don't make sense.  Rather than several snippets you should construct a short complete example.  Based on the code you've shown and described it shouldn't be much longer but it might point out subtle issues we can't see now.

Comment: You are probably better off using [c++ standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)  (e.g. `std::vector<>`) and a struct for each of the data records to read.

Comment: Also, `string PipeS[10000][3]` is a rather large amount of memory to allocate on the stack (240kB on my platform).  This would be better done dynamically, i.e. using `std::vector` as πάντα ῥεῖ already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get this error because your arrays PipeI and PipeD are just one index long in their first brackets so its like

```
PipeI[1][3]={0};
PipeD[1][6]={0};
```

if you thry to iterate through it you get the errors.
Arrays always have fixed size in c++.